# Makes the default time format to ISO8601

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an API only rails5 app. How can I make the default time format to iso8601? I don't wanna do something like `time.iso8601` one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `i18n`. Add the file `config/locales/en.yml` (or whatever locale you're using by default) and add this to it:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d" # This is the same as ISO 8601
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with active model serializer. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/582#issuecomment-49066700